# Phusion Passenger Nginx module installer v3.0.17 issue on Debian 6.0.5 amd64 due to broken package

Tags: linux, nginx, debian, passenger

I tried default Passenger Nginx installation steps, but it couldn't succeed, I am newbie to linux and ruby on rails , so guys please help me if i am doing wrong or something is wrong, upto my knowledge some package is broken in debian 6.0.5 or passenger nginx module.

I am using REE

```
ruby 1.8.7 (2012-02-08 MBARI 8/0x6770 on patchlevel 358) [x86_64-linux], MBARI 0x6770, Ruby Enterprise Edition 2012.02
```

from http://rubyenterpriseedition.googlecode.com/files/ruby-enterprise_1.8.7-2012.02_amd64_debian6.0.deb

**root@debian:~# passenger-install-nginx-module**

```
Welcome to the Phusion Passenger Nginx module installer, v3.0.17.

This installer will guide you through the entire installation process. It
shouldn't take more than 5 minutes in total.

Here's what you can expect from the installation process:

 1. This installer will compile and install Nginx with Passenger support.
 2. You'll learn how to configure Passenger in Nginx.
 3. You'll learn how to deploy a Ruby on Rails application.

Don't worry if anything goes wrong. This installer will advise you on how to
solve any problems.


Press Enter to continue, or Ctrl-C to abort.


--------------------------------------------

Checking for required software...

 * GNU C++ compiler... found at /usr/bin/g++
 * The 'make' tool... found at /usr/bin/make
 * A download tool like 'wget' or 'curl'... found at /usr/bin/wget
 * Ruby development headers... found
 * OpenSSL support for Ruby... found
 * RubyGems... found
 * Rake... found at /usr/local/bin/rake
 * rack... found
 * Curl development headers with SSL support... not found
 * OpenSSL development headers... not found
 * Zlib development headers... found

Some required software is not installed.
But don't worry, this installer will tell you how to install them.

Press Enter to continue, or Ctrl-C to abort.


Installation instructions for required software

 * To install Curl development headers with SSL support:
   Please run apt-get install libcurl4-openssl-dev or libcurl4-gnutls-dev, whichever you prefer.

 * To install OpenSSL development headers:
   Please run apt-get install libssl-dev as root.

If the aforementioned instructions didn't solve your problem, then please take
a look at the Users Guide:

  /usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/passenger-3.0.17/doc/Users guide Nginx.html
```

**root@debian:~# apt-get install libcurl4-openssl-dev**

```
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
Some packages could not be installed. This may mean that you have
requested an impossible situation or if you are using the unstable
distribution that some required packages have not yet been created
or been moved out of Incoming.
The following information may help to resolve the situation:

The following packages have unmet dependencies:
 libcurl4-openssl-dev : Depends: libssl-dev but it is not going to be installed
                        Depends: libkrb5-dev but it is not going to be installed or
                                 hurd but it is not installable
E: Broken packages
```

**root@debian:~# apt-get install libssl-dev**

```
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
Some packages could not be installed. This may mean that you have
requested an impossible situation or if you are using the unstable
distribution that some required packages have not yet been created
or been moved out of Incoming.
The following information may help to resolve the situation:

The following packages have unmet dependencies:
 libssl-dev : Depends: libssl0.9.8 (= 0.9.8o-4squeeze12) but 0.9.8o-4squeeze13 is to be installed
E: Broken packages
```

**Note:**

I tried installing  all possible libraries (libcurl4-gnutls-dev,libkrb5-dev..) suggested by passenger installation steps, everything says broken package.

**Update:**

I am using REE

ruby 1.8.7 (2012-02-08 MBARI 8/0x6770 on patchlevel 358) [x86_64-linux], MBARI 0x6770, Ruby Enterprise Edition 2012.02

Comment: Does `sudo apt-get update` help at all? If your package lists are out of date, they point to the wrong versions. An update would fetch new lists, which should match what's in the repo; then the error messages should go away ... if this was the cause of the problem.

Comment: i already tried that it doesn't help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I had the same issue with `libcurl4-openssl-dev`. Try `sudo apt-get install libcurl4-gnutls-dev` which should work just fine.

Give it a try, and if it doesn't work please let me know and I'll show you a work around to have libcurl4-openssl-dev installed.

Comment: Your solution works fantastically thanks bravo. if possible can you guide me a tutorial for passenger 3.0.17 + nginx under  debian 6 running as a production mode. I am still in confuse with passenger standalone mode , more information about my architecture is here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12210495/phusion-passenger-nginx-virtual-host-configuration-for-ruby-on-rails-applicati

Answer (score 0):

With Debian you can use the [Dotdeb repository](http://www.dotdeb.org/instructions/) and install

```
nginx-passenger
```

Comment: I am looking for passenger+nginx module not apache

Comment: can u please explain bit more about dotdeb repo , is it official release from debian?

Comment: @Sampath: No, it's a third party repository.

Comment: can i trust dotdeb?, since iam going to use for production purpose

Comment: @Sampath: It's pretty well known. It's your call, though.

Comment: I tried dotdeb , but it  also dosen't work
 , see my Error post there http://www.dotdeb.org/2012/09/26/nginx-1-2-4/