# Is ruby enterprise edition (REE) is compatible with passenger 3.0.17?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, nginx, passenger, ruby-enterprise-edition, phusion

I am using REE

```
ruby 1.8.7 (2012-02-08 MBARI 8/0x6770 on patchlevel 358) [x86_64-linux], MBARI 0x6770, Ruby Enterprise Edition 2012.02
```

from http://rubyenterpriseedition.googlecode.com/files/ruby-enterprise_1.8.7-2012.02_amd64_debian6.0.deb

Is this REE compatible with passenger 3.0.17 , for more information visit 
[Phusion Passenger Nginx module installer v3.0.17 issue on Debian 6.0.5 amd64 due to broken package](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12643845/phusion-passenger-nginx-module-installer-v3-0-17-issue-on-debian-6-0-5-amd64-due)

Answer (score 1):

Yes. Phusion Passenger supports Ruby versions all the way back to 1.8.5.